# How to mute other application sources?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm making a web-app that is doing the same as Skype, Hangouts etcetera. But when you are in a video conversation I want to make that you only hear the content from a video element (The video from another user). How can I fix this with plain JavaScript? I tried this code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var anotherAppAudio = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions);
      anotherAppAudio.mute();
});
```

Comment: do you mean audio sources outside of your webpage?

Comment: @MattEllen Yes, I mean that.

Comment: You cannot do that because the javascript engine is sandboxed to the page. The javascript of your page can only control your page.

Comment: @MattEllen But when you use Google Meet it will mute other audio.